# pandas' .concat() not inserting rows in the right place

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I'm writing a python code that will take a pandas dataframe and insert a row below each subset of "productname2"s containing a subtotal (identical to how Excel runs subtotals). When I run the code, however, all subsets are correctly subtotaled, but the row that was concatenated is not below the subset of product names as I want.

[This is the dataset (df) in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTE5Z.png)

(EDIT: There is a column to the left titled "NDC11" and is what I am referencing in the below code, however I think any column would work as long as it's not the "Scripts" column)

```
df1 = pd.concat([df, df.groupby('ProductName2', as_index=False)['Scripts'].sum()]).sort_values('ProductName2')

df1.loc[df1['NDC11'].isnull(), 'ProductName2'] = 'Subtotal'
```

[This is what I get when I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX7c5.png)

As you can see, the concatenation works for the subset "Clindamycin", but the "Isotretinoin Capsule" subset concatenates the subtotal row one row above an "Isotretinoin" ProductName2. All of the calculated subtotals are correct for the subsets, but they aren't being placed in the correct spots.

(p.s. any help on being able to name the subtotals as "Clindamycin Subtotal" or "Isotretinoin Capsule Subtotal" relative to what they are subtotaling would be awesome as well)

Comment: Can you create some scratch code that does the same thing with fake data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this achieves what you're after

```
df1 = df1.sort_values('ProductName2', ascending=True)  # Optional

# Create a new DataFrame to store the result
result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df1.columns)

# Iterate over each unique product name
for product in df1['ProductName2'].unique():
    # Filter the rows for the current product
    product_rows = df1[df1['ProductName2'] == product]

    # Calculate the subtotal for the current product
    subtotal = product_rows['Scripts'].sum()

    # Append the product rows and subtotal row to the result DataFrame
    result_df = pd.concat([result_df,
                           product_rows,
                           pd.DataFrame(
                               [[f'{product} Subtotal', '', subtotal, '']],
                               columns=df1.columns
                               )])

result_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

With fake data generated using this

```
data = [
    ['Product A', 5, 14],
    ['Product C', 3, 180],
    ['Product B', 2, 40],
    ['Product B', 4, 14],
    ['Product A', 1, 48],
    ['Product C', 6, 126]
]

# Create the DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ProductName2', 'Units', 'Scripts'])
df1['Total Amount'] = df1['Units'] * df1['Scripts']
```

I get this dataframe

[image: sample data]

Running the given code gives me this

[image: totaled data]

Comment: Thank you so much Mitchell, this problem has been making me so annoyed but this solution works perfectly! I had a few more rows of data so I added a few empty strings in the concat portion under pd.DataFrame(). I also added in units subtotal and total amount subtotals and it worked like a charm. Again, thank you so much for your help!